# Installing firefox extension on a web site

Tags: javascript, hash, firefox-addon, mozilla

I have created an extension for mozilla firefox. Now, I'm trying to distribute the extension on an simple web site. I generate a sha1 hash code from an online generator. This is the code I have in my web site:

`<script type="application/javascript">
function install (aEvent)
{
for (var a = aEvent.target; a.href === undefined;) a = a.parentNode;
var params = {
"Foo": { URL: aEvent.target.href,
Hash: aEvent.target.getAttribute("hash"),
toString: function () { return this.URL; }
}
};
InstallTrigger.install(params);
return false;
}
</script>
<a href="c:/grouAndUsersWorkSpace/MozillaAddon/createtab.xpi"
hash="sha1:a7093a2afe1a53fde114a4a7dcb3e15e57862642"
onclick="return install(event);">Install Extension!</a>`

the path of the url is local. And as a result when I start the application I got "The add-on could not be downloaded because of a connection failure on localhost".

I changed the path of the url to be: file://c:/grouAndUsersWorkSpace/MozillaAddon/createtab.xpi and with this nothing happens.

I have two questions:
1. Is that a good way to generate a hash code?
2. What should cause that connection failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I prefer to use the [CHK Checksum Utility](http://compressme.net/) to generate checksums.
2) I don't have access at the moment to verify it, but have you tried serving the extension with Apache or similar?

**Edit**

Since you used a local file, you'll need a **3** slashes instead of 2 : [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows_2) .

Tested it both ways, they both work.